# Exclude child checkbox from onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have following html code:

```
<tr class="clickable" onclick="location.href='https://www.w3schools.com'">
    <td>
        Lore ipsum
    </td>
    <td>More content</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1"></td>
</tr>
```

Now the issue is, that when I click on the checkbox, it redirects me to the onclick link. How can I exclude the checkbox from the onclick function?

All rows should be clickable, so placing the onclick to the content is not an option

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/ss12zeqk/

Comment: so why can't you just apply the `onclick` to just the content td?

Comment: Actually I have three more td's inside the table and they should all be clickable

Comment: Should have put that in the example as well, since it'll better illustrate your issue

Comment: Updated the example

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend having a function that processes this instead then.

```js
function tr_clicked(event)
{
 var the_class = event.target.className;
  var the_node = event.target.nodeName;

  if (the_node !== "INPUT" && the_class !== "checkbox")
 {
   alert("I'm going elsewhere");
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr class="clickable" onclick="tr_clicked(event)">
    <td>
      <div>
        Lore ipsum
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using the event trigger, you can see what triggered the event and proceed if necessary. I added a class to the checkbox td just to verify easier and made sure that you didn't click the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

a `jquery` solution:

```
$('tr.clickable').click(function() {
location.href='https://www.w3schools.com'
});

$('tr.clickable input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
$('tr.clickable').click(function() {
location.href='https://www.w3schools.com'
});

$('tr.clickable input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}

tr:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr class="clickable">
    <td>
      <div>
        Lore ipsum
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>More content</td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="check" value="1">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I believe it will still trigger the `tr` function when you hit the td in the checkbox

Comment: OP want exclude checkbox from `onclick ` not `td`. -> `How can I exclude the checkbox from the onclick function?` @A.Lau

Comment: I believe it would probably extend into the `td` parent of the checkbox, otherwise a simple misclick in the vicinity would also cause them to redirect.